# How to find SNMP version in Server 2012\2016\2019

Tags: snmp, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2016, windows-server-2019

I can find snmp version in linux, but not in windows, I can see the service active, but aside form that I am not sure how to tell which version was there.  When googling all i am finding is how to set it up, or is server version X compatible with SNMP3.
So for a server that has the server running, how do i find out the version?  And if it is different between the 3 server OS's please let me know the differences as I have all 3.

Thanks

Comment: If you read carefully how to set it up, you probably notice that Windows Server SNMP service only supports v1 and v2c. Microsoft spent almost no resource on that service since 2000, so for all three versions of Windows Server you mentioned there should be no difference.

Comment: I know that 1 and 2 are very similar.  On a server that already has SNMP installed, how do I find which version is currently installed?

Comment: You have no choice to select which version(s) is installed. Once you enable SNMP service, both versions are there.

Comment: Ahh, ok, thankyou for the clarification.  I did not set this up, I am auditing an existing server group, but this answer explains a bunch for me, THANKS!

Comment: Newbie question, since you answered this for me, where can I mark as answered?  And\Or give a +1 to your rep for the help, as that seems to be a thing on many forums.